# Using python's property while loading old objects

Tags: python, properties, pickle

I have a rather large project, including a class Foo which recently needed to be updated using the `@property` decorator to create custom getter and setter methods.

I also stored several instances of `Foo` on my hard drive that at some point I might need to reload. My problem is, that I cannot access the attributes decoreted with property on these old objects.

Consider the following example:

```
import pickle

# define Class and create instance
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1
foo = Foo()

# dump foo into file
with open("foo.pickle", 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(foo, handle, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# overwrite and add @property in the class definition
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = "new_foo"

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val

    @val.setter
    def val(self, val):
        self._val = val

foo_new = Foo()
print(foo_new.val)

# reload foo
with open("foo.pickle", "rb") as handle:
    foo_old = pickle.load(handle)

# try to access attributes
print(foo_old.val)
```

The last line raises:

> NameError: name '_val' is not defined

What options do I have to still access the attributes of my archived instances?

Edit: Changed `self.val` to `self._val` in the constructor of the second Foo-definition.

Comment: `val = 1` is a local, rather than a class attribute - it also has the 'wrong' name.  I think you mean `self._val = 1` and `return self._val`

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit sloppy there. I updated the code to a real working example.

Comment: Your update is still incorrect, it should be self._val = "new_foo"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166546/discussion-between-physicsguy-and-stevej).

Comment: personally, and this is way OT, I have found @property attributes to be nothing but pain in 99% of use cases .... they obfuscate what is actually happening in the code, and because there are no really private variables, they dont actually stop anyone from circumventing them anyway

Comment: @Joran Beasley to my understanding, there are two options when dealing with classes used as interfaces. Either you provide setters and getters to users of the interface, so that you can  later modify the implementation of the interface. Or you provide access directly to the attributes (foo.val), and if need be implement custom setters getters later. The former might be clearer on what's happening, the latter is more convenient during writing the initial implementation. So I'd say it depends on the scale and target of your project.

Comment: i mean in python `foo.x=5` implies to me that i want `x == 5`  setter x may cause unexpected behavior(because `foo.x = 5` implies to me that there is no logic happening) ... where as a method lik`foo.setX(5)` makes it clear to me that there is some logic going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to use a custom [`Unpickler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler), although you would need to keep the old class around (with a different name, hidden if you want) and define the logic to convert an object of the old class to the new one. Here's a basic example:

```
import pickle

# define Class and create instance
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1
foo = Foo()

# dump foo into file
with open("foo.pickle", 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(foo, handle, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Old class is kept with a new name
FooOld = Foo

# overwrite and add @property in the class definition
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = "new_foo"

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val

    @val.setter
    def val(self, val):
        self._val = val

foo_new = Foo()
print(foo_new.val)

# Custom Unpickler
class FooOldUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooOldUnpickler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def load(self):
        obj = super(FooOldUnpickler, self).load()
        if type(obj) is FooOld:
            # Object conversion logic
            newObj = Foo()
            newObj.val = obj.val
            obj = newObj
        return obj

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        # Use old class instead of new for loaded objects
        if module == __name__ and name == 'Foo':
            return FooOld
        return super(FooOldUnpickler, self).find_class(module, name)

# reload foo
with open("foo.pickle", "rb") as handle:
    # Use custom unpickler
    foo_old = FooOldUnpickler(handle).load()

# try to access attributes
print(foo_old.val)
```

Comment: Your answer is promising, but it still requires me to keep my class definition. Is there a way to also pickle that?

Comment: @physicsGuy Sorry, I forgot to answer this... I could not find a workaround without keeping the old class, you can in principle pickle a class object too, but I found when I loaded the class with pickle it would overwrite again the new class definition... But I don't know maybe there is some way.

Answer (score 3):

The pickle [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances) says:

> When a class instance is unpickled, its `__init__()` method is usually *not* invoked.

Which is why the `_val` attribute wasn't defined You can workaround that by defining a `__new__` method in the replacement `Foo` class and setting the instance attribute there:

```
import pickle

# define Class and create instance
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1
foo = Foo()

# dump foo into file
with open("foo.pickle", 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(foo, handle, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# overwrite and add @property in the class definition
class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, val=None):
        inst = super().__new__(cls)
        inst._val = "new_foo"  if val is None else val
        return inst

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val

    @val.setter
    def val(self, val):
        self._val = val

foo_new = Foo()
print(foo_new.val)  # -> new_foo

# reload foo
with open("foo.pickle", "rb") as handle:
    foo_old = pickle.load(handle)

print(foo_old.val)  # -> new_foo
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a total hack -- I'm not certain. However, I was able to reconstruct an object pickled from your first "Foo" class using the following code;

```
import pickle

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._val = "new_foo"

    @property
    def val(self):
        try:
            return self._val
        except AttributeError:
            self._val = self.__dict__['val']
            self.__dict__.pop('val')
            return self._val

    @val.setter
    def val(self, val):
        self._val = val


with open("foo.pickle", "rb") as handle:
    foo_old = pickle.load(handle)

print(foo_old.val)
```