# Sklearn KMeans cluster center change after saving and loading with Pickle

Tags: python, scikit-learn, properties, pickle, k-means

I'm training a Kmeans model for Vector Quantization and alter the Cluster Centers manually for optimization with a Variantion of the Kiefer-Wolfowitz algorithm.

I take the cluster centers, adjust them and put them in the model.
The error takes place when I save the model with pickl and load it later.
When I evalute the Quantizer I get different results after saving and loading.

To retrieve the centers I have getter and setter methods.

```
def getWeights():
   return self.kmeans.cluster_centers_.flatten()
def setWeights(weights):
   kmeans.cluster_centers_ = weights.reshape(self.clusters, self.dim)
```

To save the model I use Pickle but I also tried joblib.

```
# save
with open(os.path.join(savepath, savename + '.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self.kmeans, f)

#load
with open(os.path.join(savepath, savename + '.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
            self.kmeans  = pickle.load(f)
```

I compared the cluster centers with `np.sum(cc1 - cc2)` and got
`[-23657.44412046 -27826.84822967 -34863.87009913 -22867.6671942 -31120.73019114]`

Where are these differences comming from?
Does Pickle not save the full precision?
Or is it because of Package Version?
The Sklearn Version is 0.24.2 and Python 3.6 because of some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that the properties mess up a bit with the `cluster_centers_`. Also, are you sure it is/should be `kmeans.cluster_centers` and not `self.kmeans.cluster_centers_`?

The mystery may be related to the issue with properties reinstatiation on unpickling. Please see the question and answer here: [Using python's property while loading old objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49197079/using-pythons-property-while-loading-old-objects)

Since you have provided only a part of the code it is difficult to say if there is `__new__` missing in the class definition (`__init__` is not called on unpickling).

Comment: I forgot the `self.kmeans.cluster_centers_` in the example but not in the orignal code. And I don´t have a `__new__` method, but I create a new object and then load the cluster centers, so the `__init__` method is called.

Comment: It was misleading then. I am wondering if the linked question helped in any regard?